# Drop Down List and Selected Value

Tags: c#, html

I'm having a very hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong here.  In my Edit Item Template I have the following code for my drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd_is_active" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
 DataValueField="Enabled">
 <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="is_activeTextBox" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Enabled") %>' />
```

Here is my aspx.cs code:

```
 protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["SUB_last_modified_date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    e.Values["SUB_last_modified_by_user_id"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    e.Values["SUB_last_modified_by_user_name"] = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    e.Values["Enabled"] = ((DropDownList)(sender as ListView).InsertItem.FindControl("dd_is_active")).SelectedValue;
    e.Values["Category_ID"] = ((DropDownList)(sender as ListView).InsertItem.FindControl("dd_category")).SelectedValue;
}
protected void ListView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValues["SUB_last_modified_date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    e.NewValues["SUB_last_modified_by_user_id"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    e.NewValues["SUB_last_modified_by_user_name"] = Session["UserName"].ToString();

}
```

It seems something is either missing from my .cs code or I have the values of 1 and 0 bound incorrectly in the html code.  This exact same code works for the Insert Item Template, but the Update (or Edit Item Template) is not working correctly.

When I try to edit an item in my table I get an error stating the input string is in an incorrect format.  I know it's trying to bind the Text of "Yes" or "No" but I need to ind to the Values of either "0" or "1".  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes. Here is my C# code related to that field:   protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
               e.Values["Enabled"] = ((DropDownList)(sender as ListView).InsertItem.FindControl("dd_is_active")).SelectedValue;

Comment: I'm very new to coding so please forgive any information I might have excluded.  I have the same code in my Insert Item Template and it works just fine.

Comment: Can you share the code of SelectCommand of the SqlDataSource used in the DropDownList?

Comment: Hi there.  Right now the options are only "Yes" = 1 and "No" = 0 which are set as asp:Listitem. The SQL code to update the table is "Update [myTable] Set [Enabled] = @Enabled Where [Sub_ID] = @Sub_Id". The column is an int type that allows nulls.  I've tried changing this to a tinyint not null type but then the Insert option doesn't work. Should I be using SQL code to pull the values of 1 and 0 appropriately?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think your syntax is wrong for HiddenField value.
Instead of this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="is_activeTextBox" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Enabled") '>' />
```

It should be

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="is_activeTextBox" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Enabled")%>' />
```

Comment: I tried substituting your code but I am still getting the "Error: Input String was not in correct format".

Comment: I've seen someone use code that looked more like this:  

    <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_is_active" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Enabled")%>'>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

But my intellisense doesn't even give the option for "SelectedValue" so when I run like this I get an error stating SelectedValue is invalid bc it does not exist in the list of items

Comment: are you using this DropDownList in Listview??

Comment: Yes I have it labeled as ListView1

Comment: can you please explain in detail what is your problem actually?? what is your requirement?

Comment: Yes, in my Item Insert Template I have the same code for my drop down list as I entered above; however, it correctly inserts either a 1 or 0 value in my Enabled column of the SQL table.  

In my Edit Item Template, with the exact same code, it's trying to insert Yes or No text into the Enabled column instead of using the corresponding 1 or 0 values.  Do you have to bind data differently in the Edit Item Template than in the Insert Item Template?

Comment: do you have an error in ListView1_ItemInserting method or in sqlcommand while storing in database?

Comment: No the ListView1_ItemInserting works perfectly and I tried the Update SQL directly in SQL and it works fine too. Since I am binding the values of 1 and 0 instead of the text, what would cause the text to bind? This seems to be the issue because it is trying to insert "Yes" into the [Enabled] column instead of "1".